# Как работает beginRemoveRows()/endRemoveRows и их аналоги?

Tags: c++, qt

в доках четко написано:

beginRemoveRows():

> Note: This function emits the rowsAboutToBeRemoved() signal which
>   connected 
>       views (or proxies) must handle before the data is removed. Otherwise, the 
>       views may end up in an invalid state.

так же и в endRemoveRows()

> you must call this function after removing data from the model's underlying data store.

приходится писать вот такой вот код:

```
emit serv->sg_beginRemoveRow(1, i, pThis);
m_childItems.remove(i);
emit serv->sg_endRemovRow();
```

если раскрыть эти слоты, то там в первом begin
в конце end

почему нельзя вот такое вот:

```
emit serv->sg_beginRemoveRow(1, i, pThis);
emit serv->sg_endRemovRow();
m_childItems.remove(i);
```

то есть вначале удалить индекс в модели а затем из своей структуры.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что предполагается, что между вызовами `begin*` и `end*` модель может находиться в некорректном состоянии. Это у вас контейнер и все, но бывают модели очень сложные когда нужно и в сеть и в базу сходить, что-то преобразовать... Так вот технически бывает сложно сделать это все за один вызов функции. И еще не забывайте, что модель в Qt это не только списки/таблицы, это еще деревья.

Comment: да, и поэтому в классе наследнике от AbstractItemModel я не могу добавлять или удалять данные, поэтому приходится посылать сигналы и как-то изворачиваться вначале стер данные а затем вызвал сигналы модели чтобы она перерисовалась. Но объесните смысл работы этих бегин-эндов. Почему если делать если удаление/добавление элементов заключать в бегин/энд ошибки не будет, а если тут же, и рядов в этой же функции то будет. Как это реализовано?

Comment: Почему не можете добавлять/удалять в классе модели? В чем проблема?

    bool Model::removeRow(int row)
    {
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    // удаляете данные;
    endRemoveRows();
    ....
    }

Как реализовано можно посмотреть в исходниках.

Comment: проблема не в том что я не могу, я могу. Чтобы вы поняли, при правильной реализации работает все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что у Вас за сигналы такие sg_beginRemoveRow, sg_endRemovRow.
Методы beginInsertRows, endInsertRows должны вызывается в Вашем классе-модели, наследнике QAbstractTableModel или подобном, для того они и сделаны protected.

Правильное использование можно посмотреть в примерах qt abstractitemmodel или adressbook

endRemoveRows дает понять отображению, что изменились какие-то данные, и для указанных строк нужно перечитать данные из модели, вызовом метода data.
Если вы данные из модели будет удалять "после", то будете в view получать устаревшие значения.

Comment: Добавлю, что если не вызвать эти методы или вызвать неправильно, то может возникнуть не только неверное отображение данных в представлениях, но и крах программы, так как представление может попытаться обратиться к данным, которые уже удалены.

Comment: вы сказали то , что я уже знаю, как происходит крах программы? Да примеры, да, в документации сказано что надо делать так. НО почему если вначале вызвать beginRemove/endRemove. а затем уже удалить из контейнера, то QModelIndex уже удалился а затем я удаляю сам элемент, то объясните из-за чего может произойти крах программы.